# how do i find multiple count of value for rows in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have two table in sql database like below:

```
Table 1 : event table          Table 2 : game table

|event_id | game_id |         |game_id | game_name |
|  140    |  10     |         |  10    | football  |
|  140    |  10     |         |  11    | Cricket   |
|  140    |  10     |
|  140    |  10     |
|  140    |  11     |
|  140    |  11     |
|  140    |  11     |
```

Now i want the result like below:

```
|game_name | Count |
| football |   4   |
| Cricket  |   3   |
```

I have tried the query:

```
SELECT g.g_name, count(g.g_name) FROM game_table g INNER JOIN event_table e ON g.game_id = e.game_id WHERE event_id = '140';
```

but this query is given me total count not particular count of particular game name.
so how can i find counts of particular game_name?

Comment: Your query is fine, just add `GROUP BY g.g_name`

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Amazing it is working.. thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT g.g_name, count(g.g_name) 
FROM game_table g INNER JOIN event_table e ON g.game_id = e.game_id 
WHERE event_id = '140'
GROUP BY g.g_name;
```